# Efficiency of OR statement

Tags: performance, query-optimization, processing-efficiency

In our Product table (< 200K records) , we list which "Lists" the product can appear on in our webpage

```
Product    char(10)   Key
InList1    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList2    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList3    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList4    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList5    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList6    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList7    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList8    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList9    char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList10   char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList11   char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList12   char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList13   char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
InList14   char(1)    NonKey   Y/N
```

In my SSRS parameter, I have a ListNames as Value and Labels that the user can select 1 to All.

I then send a single parameter into a Stored Procedure using JOIN(@List,";").

What I need to do is find a way to NOT continue checking all List#'s after then first one is found.

At the moment, I am doing the following:

```
-- **********************************************************************
select ' ' into #List
insert into #List
SELECT trim(value ) List
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ';');
-- **********************************************************************
select Product
into #temp_Product
from ProductTable  with(nolock);
-- **********************************************************************

select Product from #temp_Product with(nolock)
where (
    ('List1' in (select List from #List) and InList1 = 'Y') or 
    ('List2' in (select List from #List) and InList2 = 'Y') or 
    ('List3' in (select List from #List) and InList3 = 'Y') or 
    ('List4' in (select List from #List) and InList4 = 'Y') or 
    ('List5' in (select List from #List) and InList5 = 'Y') or 
    ('List6' in (select List from #List) and InList6 = 'Y') or 
    ('List7' in (select List from #List) and InList7 = 'Y') or 
    ('List8' in (select List from #List) and InList8 = 'Y') or 
    ('List9' in (select List from #List) and InList9 = 'Y') or 
    ('List10' in (select List from #List) and InList10 = 'Y') or 
    ('List11' in (select List from #List) and InList11 = 'Y') or 
    ('List12' in (select List from #List) and InList12 = 'Y') or 
    ('List13' in (select List from #List) and InList13 = 'Y') or 
    ('List14' in (select List from #List) and InList14 = 'Y')
      )
```

It is my understanding that SQL will check ALL possibilities for correctness even if you need only one to be true.  Because a single Product can appear in one-to-many lists, the issue I am having is a performance issue of having to check each possibility with an OR statement.  What is the most efficient way of checking for at least one statement being TRUE?

In other words, what I'd like to do is if 'List1','List3','List4'' & 'List5' were passed into the SP, if a product is found in all of these lists, the query would **NOT** perform the other validations, or STOP further validations, after finding the first TRUE statement...Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks in advance.

I tried the above code